# Can you tell if an object is awaiting an async member function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await

I'm working on the client-side of a web application using TypeScript.

I have my own "framework" where I've developed a class (ViewBinder) that uses an async "show" method to load information from the server, extract HTML, and insert it into the document within a parent "placeholder" element.  Its derived classes can then "bind" data from a client state object to the loaded HTML.

Here is some of the code from that class for reference (not an executable example):

```
export class ViewBinder extends PropertyChangedNotifier {
    // Lots of member stuff not shown for brevity...

    public async show(callbackAfterShow?: (wasSuccessful: boolean) => void): Promise<HtmlLoadViewResult> {
        this.showWasCanceled = false;
        const loadResult = await this.loadView();
        if (this.showWasCanceled) {    // Helps my situation some but not fully
            // If this.clear() was called during loadView, we just move on...
            loadResult.wasCanceled = true;
        } else {
            // HERE is where I can have a problem: if this.clear() is called
            // while a derived class is doing its setupAfterShowing, the underlying
            // HTML will be removed and the attempt to setup (binding data to the
            // HTML) will cause an unwanted error.
            await this.setupAfterShowing(loadResult);
            // CODE REMOVED FOR BREVITY
        }
        return loadResult;
    }

    public clear(): void {
        // If the show function is awaiting anything, tell it it was canceled
        // BUT: what I WANT to do is somehow wait until show() is done before
        // continuing the execution of this function... see the question text
        this.showWasCanceled = true;
        this.localViewBinders.forEach((viewBinder) => viewBinder?.clear());
        this.localBindingContexts.forEach((context) => context?.clear());
        if (this.parentElement) {
            this.parentElement.innerHTML = "";
            if (this.isModalDialog) {
                this.parentElement.remove();
            } else {
                this.collapse();
            }
            this.parentElement = null;  // We are no longer associated with the element
            this.notifyPropertyChanged("visibility");
            this.removeAllPropertyChangedListeners();
        }
    }

}
```

Note that derived classes will develop `setupAfterShowing` methods that "bind" data from the client state object to the HTML that has been loaded (and can call `show` on their own "child" ViewBinders).  There is also a `clear` command that removes all the HTML from the parent element and clears out all the "data bindings" as well.

However, there are rare times when the underlying client state object changes while a ViewBinder is awaiting the `show` command (during the `loadView` or `setupAfterShowing` calls), and those changes cause the code to call the `clear` method, removing the body of the parent element where it was supposed to insert it's HTML and bind the data.

In general, if the ViewBinder doesn't find a parent element or can't find a place in that element to display data, I consider that a bug and I throw an error.  However, in this case the HTML will be removed "legitimately" while the async code is awaiting results.

Note that I've tried to use `showWasCanceled` to avoid this issue, but there are too many cases of potential issues inside derived `setupAfterShowing` methods to ensure I'm always aborting if `showWasCanceled` is set to `true`.

SO, here is my question:

Is there a way for my `clear` function determine if the `show` function is "being awaited" and pause execution until "show" is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is create some fields to hold such info, e.g.

```
private promise;
private resolve;
private reject;

init() {
  this.promise = new Promise((res, rej)=>{
    this.resolve = res;
    this.reject= rej;
  });
}

public async show(...) {
  ...
  resolve(null); // or reject if any error thrown above
}

public async clear() {
  await this.promise;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I haven't played around enough with raw Promises to have recognized this as a solution.  So once the promise is created, any await on that promise will be waiting until the promise calls its resolve or reject function, right?  I'd probably make the promise an optional property and create it at the start of `show` so I can run the `clear` method if it is undefined or await it if it is defined.  That way there's no issue if `clear` is called for some reason before `show`.  Can't test it easily because I have to first make ALL my clear calls do awaits, but it looks like a good answer.

Comment: yes, that promise is a signal so `clear` method has to wait for it before proceeding with the rest of its actual logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept the answer from @ABOS since it provides a solution in the spirit of an async/await process (having `clear()` await a promise that `show()` can resolve).

However, I ended up taking a somewhat old-school approach and wanted to document it here in case others found it useful.

Note that this also prevented me from having to make `clear` an `async` method (which caused me to go `async` "all-the-way-down" in a lot of places).

Here's the description:

First I added two booleans to the class: `clearWasCalled` and `isRunningShow`.

When `show()` is called, it sets `this.clearWasCalled = false` and `this.isRunningShow = true`.  At the end of `show()`, it sets `this.isRunningShow = false` and if `this.clearWasCalled === true` it will call `this.clear()`.

When `clear()` is called, it checks if `this.isRunningShow === true`, and if so, it sets `this.clearWasCalled = true` and exits.

So, when awaiting the `show()` method, if something calls `clear()`, it does not interrupt the `show()` function but merely sets a flag.  When `show()` is done, it checks whether the flag was set and if so it makes sure the `clear` action is accomplished.

Here is the basic idea in code:

```
export class ViewBinder extends PropertyChangedNotifier {
    // Lots of member stuff not shown for brevity...

    public clearWasCalled = false;
    public isRunningShow = false;

    public async show(callbackAfterShow?: (wasSuccessful: boolean) => void): Promise<HtmlLoadViewResult> {
        this.clearWasCalled = false;
        this.isRunningShow = true;
        const loadResult = await this.loadView();
        if (this.clearWasCalled === false) {    // Just in case...
            // If this.clear() was called during loadView, we just move on...
            loadResult.wasCanceled = true;
        } else {
            await this.setupAfterShowing(loadResult);
            // CODE REMOVED FOR BREVITY
        }
        this.isRunningShow = false;
        if (this.clearWasCalled) {
            this.clear();
            loadResult.wasCanceled = true;
        }
        return loadResult;
    }

    public clear(): void {
        // If we're running a show method, don't clear until it's done
        if (this.isRunningShow) {
            this.clearWasCalled = true;
            return;
        }

        // PERFORM CLEAR ACTIONS...
    }

}
```